# Form submission bypasses javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html

Submission below bypasses javascript validation. Is it because onclick even or I'm missing something?

Thanks

**FORM**

```
<form name="myprofile" action="do_update" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_submission(this.name)">
   <input type="text" id="text_fullname" name="text_fullname" value="" maxlength="100" />
   <div id="submit_button" onclick="document.myprofile.submit()">SUBMIT</div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function validate_submission(formname)
{
    alert(formname); return false;
}
```

Comment: @Philip — The benefit of JavaScript form checking is that it is *much faster* then a round trip to the server. That is a real benefit, and this question is not pointless.

Comment: ie: visual aid.. Sorry mis-read the q, I thought he was trying to bypass another sites validation, not had my coffee, continue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add in an extra submission script, and call that from the div...

```
<script>
    function validate_submission(formname)
    {
        var is_valid = false;

        if (formname == 'myprofile')
        {
            is_valid = true;
        }

        perform_submit(formname, is_valid);
    }

    function perform_submit(formname, is_valid)
    {
        if (is_valid === true)
        {
            document.myprofile.submit()
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Invalid');
        }
    }
</script>
<form name="myprofile" action="do_update" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_submission(this.name)">
   <input type="text" id="text_fullname" name="text_fullname" value="" maxlength="100" />
   <div id="submit_button" onclick="validate_submission('myprofile')">SUBMIT</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Just discovered that if I add `if (formname == 'myprofile') { return true; } else { return false; }` doesn't validate form. Is it normal behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

It isn't so much that you are using `onclick` as that you are using `form_ref.submit()` which submits a form without firing the `submit` event.

Your options:

- Use a real submit button (and don't call `submit()` with JS). This is the best option. It will show up in screen reader forms modes. It can be tabbed to. It will work if JS is not turned on.
- Call the validation function and check the result before calling `submit()`.

Comment: Thanks for the controbution